# failed to fetch data from JSON response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I confess, its a very basic question. But I am actually fed up with it. I am just trying to send my current time in JSON format from my action method to the view. In the view code, I am trying to fetch the result using jQuery ajax() method. But while in the success attribute, I am unable to fetch the result from the response. Tried numerous ways like response.d etc. But ended up with nothing almost.

Here goes the relevant code snippets:

**Action method:**

```
 public JsonResult GetDateTest()
        {
            return Json(DateTime.Now.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**script in the view:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Button1").click(function (e) {

            $.ajax({


                type: 'POST',

                url: '@Url.Action("GetDateTest","GetDate")',

                data: '{}',

                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (response) {

                    //how can I read the date here and display it on the standard //controls like a label?

                },

                error: function (e) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Help me to figure it out with proper explanation

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to find out what the `response` object looks like, then you'll know what property to access in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get data as `json`, modify your controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetDateTest()
{
    return Json(new { date = DateTime.Now.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

add success function:

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#someLabel").html(response.date);
},
```

html

```
<div id="someLabel"></div>
```

Comment: How can I get an object's property like this ? say I have an employee class like this: public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    }...How can I retrieve the id,Name or salary value inside the ajax() method ?

Comment: if use `return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` Json will convert your class to Json data.

Comment: I need one more help from you..Suppose I have a form..I want to submit all its Text Boxs' data in a single ajax post..How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760114/mvc4-ajax-pass-complete-model-to-controller/14760193#14760193

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
>   ...
>       "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

So, in your case the response should be already parsed as JSON and returned as a javascript string.

Since you don't pass any data, you can just use the default method of GET and reduce your example to

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDateTest","GetDate")',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

If you don't need an error callback, you can use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead and simplify it further

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDateTest","GetDate")',
          function (response) {
              console.log(response);
          });
```

**Update** to comment:

To access an object's properties, you must encode it as a JSON object

```
{
    "id": 423,
    "name": "john doe",
    "salary": 50000
}
```

and in the ajax success function, you can access it as the response's properties

```
success: function(data) {
    var id = data.id;
    var name = data.name;
    var salary = data.salary;
    // do something with data properties
}
```

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud You must encode it as a JSON object, see updated answer.